# Create objects from files in folder in Processing

Tags: directory, processing

Is possible with a for loop to look up the items in a folder and create corresponding objects in Processing?

Comment: Yes? Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: what do you mean by objects? (shapes, structs, ect...)?